# Is there a way to store an anonymous delegate in a viewstate?

Tags: c#, serialization, delegates, webforms, viewstate

In a `WebControl`, i have a property `Filters` defined like this :

```
public Dictionary<string, Func<T, bool>> Filters
{
    get
    {
       Dictionary<string, Func<T, bool>> filters =
               (Dictionary<string, Func<T, bool>>)ViewState["filters"];
       if (filters == null)
       {
          filters = new Dictionary<string, Func<T, bool>>();
          ViewState["filters"] = filters;
       }
       return filters;
    }
 }
```

This webcontrol is a `DataSource`, i created this property because i want to have the possiblity to filter data easily, eg:

```
//in page load    
DataSource.Filters.Add("userid", u => u.UserID == 8);
```

It works great, however, if I change code to this :

```
//in page load    
int userId = int.Parse(DdlUsers.SelectedValue);
DataSource.Filters.Add("userid", u => u.UserID == userId);
```

It doesn't works anymore, I get this error :

> Type System.Web.UI.Page in Assembly '...' is not marked as
>   serializable.

What happened :

1. The serializer inspect the dictionary. It sees it contains a anonymous delegate (lambda here)
2. Since the delegate is defined in a class, it tries to serialize the whole class, in this case System.Web.UI.Page
3. This class is not marked as Serializable
4. It throws an exception because of 3.

**Is there any convenient solution to solve this ?** I cannot mark all web pages where i use the datasource as [serializable] for obvious reasons.

---

**EDIT 1** : something I don't understand. If I store the `Dictionary` in the `Session` object (which use a `BinaryFormatter` vs `LosFormatter` for `ViewState`), it works ! I have no idea how it is possible. Maybe `BinaryFormatter` can serialize any class, even these who are not `[serializable]` ?

---

**EDIT 2** : smallest code to reproduce the problem :

```
void test()
{
    Test test = new Test();
    string param1 = "parametertopass";
    test.MyEvent += () => Console.WriteLine(param1);

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
       BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
       bf.Serialize(ms, test); //bang
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Test
{
   public event Action MyEvent;
}
```

Comment: "it works ! I have no idea how ..." : Session data remains server-side, in-memory. It will start to break when you move to 2+ servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, here is how i did it :

I modified Dictionary definition like this:

```
Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<Func<T, object[], bool>, object[]>>
```

(`KeyValuePair` is serializable, just like `Dictionary`)

and created a new `Add()` function :

```
public void Add(string key, Func<T, object[], bool> filter, params object[] args)
{
    this.Add(key, new KeyValuePair<Func<T, object[], bool>, object[]>
          (filter, args));
}
```

Now filters can be set this way :

```
int userId = int.Parse(DdlUsers.SelectedValue);
DataSource.Filters.Add("userid", (u, args) => u.UserID == (int)args[0], userId);
```

It works, because now captured variables are no more a part the delegate, but given as parameters of the delegate.

Answer (score 4):

Good question. I can confirm your diagnose (with one tiny correction: The infrastructure tries to serialize the closure class which probably contains a reference to your page).

You can define your own closure class and have that serialized:

```
[Serializable] class Closure { int userId; bool Filter(User u) { ... } };
```

That is not convenient, though.

I suggest you use a different pattern: Don't serialize "code". Serialize the data used by the filter:

```
class FilterSettings { int userId; int someOtherFiler; string sortOrder; ... }
```

Although I cannot point to the exact reason why I would prefer that I intuitively know that is a better approach.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I am not sure how second proposition will work. Who will instantiate and hold the instance of FilterSettings class ? If its the page, isn't there any risk that serializer will reach the page as well ? Can you provide more code about how to use this solution ?

Comment: Storing a class whose fields you precisely control will never reference the page. There is no way the serializer can reach the page starting from Closure or FilterSettings.

Comment: I still cannot make it work even with you suggestions. I have added a sample of code at the bottom of question that will reproduce the problem. Can you have a look and give me hint ?

Comment: I guess the compiler-created closure class is not [Serializable]. That's why you need to roll your own. If you want to serialize a function, make that function an instance member of the closure class and create the delegate like this: new Action(myClosure.InstanceMethod). You can't use a lambda.